# Interesting Problem: Organizing objects into bins based on common properties

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say we have a set of objects. Each of these objects has a letter, a number, and a shape. That dataset might look something like this:

[image: DataSet]

I'd like to write an algorithm that would sort these into 'Bins'. So that they would show what possibilities have been covered in the set, and what has left to be covered. By the end, you would have a set of Bins. Which would allow you to access all of the objects which have been organized into them.

So the organized set would look something like this:

```
Bin 1: [ (A, B) , (0), (Circle, Square) ] *(grouping line 1, 2, 7, 8)*

Bin 2: [ (A) , (0), (Triangle) ]

Bin 3: [ (A), (1), (Circle, Square) ] *(grouping line 5, 6)*

Bin 4: [ (B), (1), (Circle) ] 

Needed: [ (B), (0), (Triangle) ]

Needed: [ (B), (1), (Square, Triangle) ]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to tackle this problem? Or how to deal with the issue of having one line fit into multiple slots?

For example, this set could group line 5 into

`[ (A, B), (1), (Circle) ]` or `[(A), (1), (Circle, Square) ]` and both would be valid.

So maybe there would have to be some check for redundancy? Maybe a check to see if the object is already contained in a Bin?

Any help, thoughts, or discussion would be appreciated.

Comment: What decides the bins?

Comment: The need to be able to access the objects in the bin. The user should be able to select a bin and have all of the objects that were put into that category returned. So maybe bins aren't necessary. and it could be done with a modified select? Bins just seemed like an easy way to analogize it

Comment: If you're requiring organized user access, just leave this in the data frame form and supply a simple inquiry interface that allows the user to specify a display hierarchy.  A data frame filter will handle the selection quite nicely.

Comment: What's your exact question? Are you asking how to define the bins in code? Are you asking how to iterate the list and add items to the bins? What do you want the output to be? What do the "Needed" lines mean? Are those bins that you've defined but don't have any items? What do you do if there is an item that doesn't fit into any bin? You've asked for help in solving a problem, but you haven't fully defined the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't organize into bins at all; leave the triples expanded.

First, generate a reference list of all needed combinations: {A,B} x {0, 1} x {Circle, Square, Triangle}.
Now, simply take the set difference between the reference list and the input list.  What remains is the set of combinations you have yet to cover.

Comment: This makes sense for getting what remains, but it doesn't group the input.